# getting context in java android

Tags: android

hey i have an android application in which i monitor gmail server in a thread in background..this thread runs infinitely ...on getting a mail in the mailbox I have to make a toast..but i am not able to get the context of current activity(since there are multiple activities in the app)...how to get context of current running activity or may be application..getApplicationcontext gives null.

Comment: Is the actviity a child of some tabHost...?

Comment: Can you post some code please, because if you had an activity called ActMain and then called ActMain.this or getApplicationContext() from it, they should work.

Answer (score 10):

If you're running an `Activity` or a `Service`, both **are** `Context` themselves, so calling `this` suffice. On any callback method for a listener, `this` will refer to the listener, not to the `Activity`. You can refer to the `Context` using any `View`:

```
Context context = myView.getContext();
```

Comment: i am not running an activity or service i am running a seperate thread  since this monitoring requires infinitely running thread ..i cannot use service that will block my other activities in foreground .

Comment: But that thread must have been started somewhere. Create a field in your `Runnable` class that points to the original `Activity` (you can do it in the constructor itself `MyRunnable = new MyRunnable(this);`

Comment: i tried dat but when i toast from the thread i get a looper error something like looper not prepared..

Comment: @user, without the code, and without the exact error, I can't do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

In toasts and listeners and everywhere, if you need to get resources, You could use

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel)
```

It has absolutely universal placement, but supports only system resources.

Answer (score 2):

Use **this** or **getApplicationContext()** to get the current context.
For example,

```
Context mContext=this;
```

or

```
Context mContext=getApplicationContext();
```

If the actvity is any child Acivity of some tabHost, then try
**getParent().getApplicationContext()** also.

Comment: getApplicationContext() works great for me, that needs to use inside a Camera PictureTaken Listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context of the Activity by calling on the Class name. For instance, if you Activity is called from inside `MainActivity` you can get the context by typing:

`Context context = this;`